# How to install .NET performance diagnostics tools Azure Build Pipelines

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Visual Studio/.NET has a lot of different performance tools like VSDiagnostics.exe. We want to establish a build pipeline for the sole purpose to diagnose the whole application and report possible memory and event handler leaks, as well as some memory und performance diagnostics.

The problem is that obviously visual studio needs to be installed which is a problem on many build servers that need to have all these prerequisites installed - it is simply too time consuming to keep them up to date.

My question is if there is some sort of installation that I can install in a build step for the diagnostics to ensure the necessary tools are installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Measure application performance from the command line Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profile-apps-from-command-line?view=vs-2022#prerequisites)

> To collect performance information on a remote machine without Visual Studio installed, install the Remote Tools for Visual Studio on the remote machine.

Here is the download link of Remote Tools for Visual Studio: [Download and Install the remote tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2022#download-and-install-the-remote-tools)

I downloaded the `VS_RemoteTools.exe` and uploaded it to my repo.

[image]

Then with the following script I can install the `VS_RemoteTools.exe` on the agent.

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: install VS_RemoteTools.exe
    inputs:
      script: VS_RemoteTools.exe /install /quiet
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: list files in the folder
    inputs:
      script: >-
        c:
        cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 17.0\Team Tools\DiagnosticsHub\Collector
        dir
```

Result：

```
2023-11-17T06:40:03.1123890Z  Directory of C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 17.0\Team Tools\DiagnosticsHub\Collector
……
2023-11-17T06:40:03.1162656Z 10/20/2023  09:17 AM           137,144 VSDiagnostics.exe
```

[image]

**Update:**

I got the download link from the download page. (Not sure if it will change when there is an update.)

[image]

Then we can use the PowerShell task to download it and don't need the manual download step.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/RemoteTools.amd64ret.enu.exe' -OutFile 'VS_RemoteTools.exe'
      dir
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      VS_RemoteTools.exe /install /quiet 
      c:
      cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 17.0\Team Tools\DiagnosticsHub\Collector"
      dir
```